# Coercing Clojure's PersistentArrayMap to Java's Map<String, String>

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to send a client identification to IMAP server using com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore's id method. The problem is that it requires a `Map<String, String>` as an argument, so the call

```
(.id store (HashMap. {"foo" "bar"}))
```

fails with `IllegalArgumentException`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I fail to see how Clojure'S PersistentArrayMap is related: you're handing over a `java.util.HashMap`, aren't you? Quite obviously the object then is a perfect `Map<String, String>`, so I would expect that you have a different problem.

Comment: @schaueho is right, perhaps I answered too fast. In fact, `(HashMap. {"foo" "bar"})` throws `IllegalArgumentException`. Have you tried with just `(.id store {"foo" "bar"})`?

Comment: @nberger `(HashMap. {"foo" "bar"})` itself does not throw anything. It returns perfectly valid HashMap, which seems to implement Map interface. Of course I tried `(.id store {"foo" "bar"})` to no avail.

Comment: @schaueho well, that was my question from the start – what might be wrong with my approach?

Comment: @lumrandir what do you mean with "I tried `(.id store {"foo" "bar"})` to no avail."? What does it return? Does it throw an exception? In that case, can you show the exception and stacktrace?

Comment: @nberger it throws an exception; see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/lumrandir/c0a06758a9264aa527af) please.

Comment: @nberger and [here](https://gist.github.com/lumrandir/1bd7e64a546cacd742d8) is the code itself.

Comment: @lumrandir I assume the stacktrace is the same when you change the code to use the `HashMap.` variant?

Comment: @schaueho yes, it is the same.

Comment: @lumrandir maybe it's just that the method does not exist. What version of javax.mail are you using? From the [java mail docs](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPStore.html#id-java.util.Map-) I see that the `id` method is available only since version 1.5.1

Comment: See [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19592023/1389573) to see why the confusing `IllegalArgumentException` exception might be thrown instead of something more clear

Comment: @nberger thanks, that really was stupid of me. I've rewritten this part in Java just to discover that the method really does not exist. I have been using older version of javax.mail all along.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3770360/1389573

Short story: you need to define an interface in Java specifying the exact type, then implement that interface in clojure.

Comment: I don't think this is really required here, cf. the [answer by Stuart Sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689391/3098550) in the same discussion.

Comment: I've tried `(def r (reify ITypedMap (typedMap [this m] m)))` and then `(.typedMap r {"foo" "bar"})`. It still returns `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`.

Comment: Please see the comments on your question. Have you tried with just `(.id store {"foo" "bar"})`?